# What is the difference between a dropdown menu and radio buttons?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, custom-list

I'm working on a list for a project at work and I want there to be two options for a particular list column, and I was hoping to use radio buttons. I set up the column with the "Choice" for the type of information, and selected the radio buttons for the display choice. When I look at the column I've created, it looks literally exactly the same as a dropdown menu - there are no differences that I can notice. Is this how it's supposed to work, or is there something not working correctly on my end? I'm not sure why they would have two different options that have no apparent differences what-so-ever. I was just hoping for something simple like that image attached.[image: Simple radio buttons.]

Answer (score 4):

In classic the two display modes looked like this:
[image]

In modern UI it has been <strike>improved</strike> changed to this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the classic SharePoint list the display mode for "Radio Buttons" and "Dropdown" is different. But in the modern experience, both options are displayed as a dropdown.

However, the functionality is same for both options such as you can select only one option.

You can give a suggestion by clicking "Feedback" button at the bottom right corner of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that there is no way to un-check a radio group once a slection is made - you have to select at least one option. A drop down allows you to uncheck a selection.